# Native StatusBar Text

Tags: vba, excel

I have done some research here and in Google.. with no success unfortunately. All I am getting is a lot of information about custom progress bars. It's all nice and clear, however, what I am looking for is to have a label on a userform to reflect the native status/progress text that comes on the Excel status bar (bottom left and right). I find it more dynamic and gives better progress status and info (especially when refreshing SQL data)

Any luck an API function (or whatever!) could do the job??

Cheers,
Amine

Comment: Take a look at the `Application.StatusBar` property.  MSDN has info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835916(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I am aware of application.status, this does only write custom status on the progress bar, but it doesn't read the native status Excel puts each time there is an operation running..